# I use ESP32 (pubsubclient) It's offten reconnect : will terminate because peer closed TCP connection

Tags: rabbitmq, mqtt, esp32

I use ESP32 with pubsubclient library It's offten reconnect.

I install RabbitMQ on Google cloud compute Centos7

And my rabbitMq log show

```
[info] <0.25824.7>MQTT connection "xx.xx.xx.xx:56547 -> xx.xx.xx.xx:1883" will terminate because peer closed TCP connection

[info] <0.26305.7> Closing all channels from connection 'xx.xx.xx.xx:56547 -> 10.148.0.8:1883' because it has been closed (edited)
```

Comment: Show us your ESP32 code...we can answer your question better that way ;)   If you don't specify a keepalive value, and there is no traffic, the connection will auto-close.

Comment: I use default keepalive value 15 sec, But my client will send Public a sensor value every 3 sec. Now i change MQTT broker to EMQX but still can’t resolve.